# Subplot hides xlabel

Tags: matplotlib

When I run this in IPython:

```
r = (100, 300)
b = 100
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.subplot(3,1,1)
plt.xlabel('Picker time (ms)')
plt.hist(sequential['X0'], range=r, bins=b, color='blue')
plt.subplot(3,1,2)
plt.hist(stateful['X0'], range=r, bins=b, color='green')
plt.subplot(3,1,3)
plt.hist(standard['X0'], range=r, bins=b, color='red')
```

The `xlabel` text of the first plot gets lost under the second.  Here's the plot:

[image]

You can just see the top of the "P" sticking out.  How do I provide `xlabel`s for subplots without this happening?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `plt.tight_layout()` to adjust the subplots so that the x-label is visible.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to @Molly's excellent suggestion a more manual approach is to use

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.1)

Since your x axes are all the same, I would suggest setting `hspace=0.0` and removing the x axis labels (use `plt.set_xticklabels([])`). This saves space and reduces the amount of repeated information.

Comment: Note that `sharex` parameter can be set to `True` to obtain what you suggest (there are other possibilities, see the [doc](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html)), i.e. editing the original code: `plt.subplot(3,1,1, sharex=True)`